# How to check if component has proper value in props from mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am working on a component which helps me manage the user roles. Depending on the role, I want to control what the application shows. I am passing permissions to `UserAccess` component and if the value from the store includes that permission, it will show the other component. Also I want to check if the component gets a proper value from `mapStateToProps`.

Component:

```
export function UserAccess({ userRoles, permission, ...props }: any) {

    if (userRoles.includes(permission)) {
        return props.children
    }
    return ''
}

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {    

    return {
        userRoles: state.roles ? state.roles : []
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserAccess)
```

Usage:

```
<UserAccess permission={'admin'}>Some component</UserAccess>
```

Test:

```
const mockStore = configureStore();
const store = mockStore({roles: "admin"})

it("should map state to props", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store} ><UserAccess ></UserAccess></Provider>)
    expect(wrapper.find(UserAccess).prop('userRoles')).toBe('admin');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test that as follow:

```
describe('User Access', () => {
  let store;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      userRoles: {
        role: 'admin',
      },
    });
  });
  it('should render UserAcess with the correct props', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <UserAccess />
      </Provider>
    );

    const container = wrapper.find(UserAccess);
    expect(container.find(UserAccess).props().userRoles).to.eql({ role: 'admin' });
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer jank. But the problem is, that
container.find(UserAccess).props().userRoles
returns undefined. 

And my question, why you use .find() twice?

Comment: The first find() is used to capture <UserAccess> container component. Then I am using another find() to assert the props. Can you specify which part of container.find().props() returns undefined?